# How to handle more than one model into a template/route in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I would like to know which is the best practice to handle this common scenario.

I would like to display inside the index page a form for **creating some model**, and after that show 4 nodes with little-info about the last 4 of that model store.

So, my first idea was something like:

**app/index/template.hbs** (im using pod's)

```html
...
<div> 
   {{form-creator-component o=model}}}
</div>
<div>
   <h3>Last 4</h3>
   {{#each model2 as |element| }}
      {{litle-info o=element }}
   {{\each}}
</div>
.....
```

But for doing that, I would need to have 2 models in the same template (and route), which looks kind of weird and I've seen nowhere in docs nor in guides. So, I assume I'm doing something in the wrong way :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need two different sets of Async data from a single model hook, the best approach is to use `Ember.RSVP.hash`.

This will await multiple promises and then resolve to an object.

For instance if you had blogs and comments you needed to load, your route would look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      blogs: this.store.findAll(`blog`),
      comments: this.store.findAll(`comment`),
    });
  }
});
```

Then in your template, you can use this data as `model.blogs` and `model.comments`.